# Got "Missing Signature" when running "mvn deploy"

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I was trying to release a Java package via `mvn deploy` but got a `Missing Signature` error. Please help me to fix this error. Thank you!

> Note: I am not very good at asking good questions, please point it out if I should improve this question to make it useful for others.

The command line:

`mvn clean source:jar javadoc:jar package deploy`

The error message:

```
[ERROR] Rule failure while trying to close staging repository with ID "comaliyun-1894".
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Nexus Staging Rules Failure Report
[ERROR] ==================================
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Repository "comaliyun-1894" failures
[ERROR]   Rule "signature-staging" failures
[ERROR]     * Missing Signature: '/com/aliyun/aliyun-java-sdk-release-test/1.1.1/aliyun-java-sdk-release-test-1.1.1-sources.jar.asc' does not exist for 'aliyun-java-sdk-release-test-1.1.1-sources.jar'.
[ERROR]     * Missing Signature: '/com/aliyun/aliyun-java-sdk-release-test/1.1.1/aliyun-java-sdk-release-test-1.1.1-javadoc.jar.asc' does not exist for 'aliyun-java-sdk-release-test-1.1.1-javadoc.jar'.
[ERROR]     * Missing Signature: '/com/aliyun/aliyun-java-sdk-release-test/1.1.1/aliyun-java-sdk-release-test-1.1.1.jar.asc' does not exist for 'aliyun-java-sdk-release-test-1.1.1.jar'.
[ERROR]     * Missing Signature: '/com/aliyun/aliyun-java-sdk-release-test/1.1.1/aliyun-java-sdk-release-test-1.1.1.pom.asc' does not exist for 'aliyun-java-sdk-release-test-1.1.1.pom'.
```

My configurations:

in pom.xml:

```
    <licenses>
            <license>
                    <name></name>
                    <url></url>
                    <distribution></distribution>
            </license>
    </licenses>
    <scm>
            <url></url>
            <connection></connection>
    </scm>
    <developers>
            <developer>
                    <id>XXX</id>
                    <name>XXX</name>
                    <email>XXX@XXX.com</email>
            </developer>
    </developers>  
<distributionManagement>
<snapshotRepository>
    <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
</snapshotRepository>
<repository>
    <id>sonatype-nexus-staging</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
</repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

and

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
<configuration>
    <skip>true</skip>
</configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>sign</goal>
             </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
 <plugin>
 <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.3</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <configuration>
          <serverId>sonatype-nexus-staging</serverId>
          <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
          <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

in settings.xml:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository/>
  <interactiveMode/>
  <usePluginRegistry/>
  <offline/>
  <pluginGroups/>

<servers>
<server>
    <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
    <username>XXXX</username>
    <password>XXXXXX</password>
</server>
<server>
    <id>sonatype-nexus-staging</id>
    <username>XXXXX</username>
    <password>XXXXXX</password>
</server>       
</servers>

  <mirrors/>
  <proxies/>

<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>sonatype-nexus-staging</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <gpg.executable>gpg2</gpg.executable>
        <gpg.passphrase>XXXXXXX</gpg.passphrase>
    </properties>
</profile>
</profiles>

  <activeProfiles/>
</settings>
```

Comment: Your maven-gpg-plugin is disabled:   <configuration>
    <skip>true</skip>
</configuration>

Comment: @rseddon Thank you! Turns out I can not skip the gpg key verification.

Answer (score -1):

Full deployment instruction for Central and OSSRH can be found in the guide at http://central.sonatype.org/pages/producers.html. Specifically have a look at http://central.sonatype.org/pages/apache-maven.html